# What does this quote by Paul Halmos mean?

Tags: mathematicians, quote, archimedes

I came across the following quote by the famous mathematician Paul Halmos:

> A clever graduate student could teach Fourier something new, but surely no one claims that he could teach Archimedes to reason better.

What does it mean, and what is the context? It seems as if Halmos wasn't fond of Archimedes' methods of reasoning, which is quite intriguing.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Apparently, Paul R. Halmos, *I Want to Be a Mathematician*, Springer 1985, p. 205 (at the bottom of the page)

Comment: Points out the difference between knowing things and being able to deduce things (solve problems).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The meaning of the quote is more likely to be, that Archimedes' reasoning was on such a high level, that no one (example: the clever graduate student) could teach him to reason better because Archimedes knew all about how to do that already.